# Bootstrap nested grid columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

When nesting a bootstrap grid within the column(s) of another grid, does the child grid get its own 12 columns, or does it only get the number of columns available in the parent grid?

For example:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6>
                    <span>Am I out of column space here, or do I get 6 more?</span>
                <div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when you divide a row with two columns "col-md-6" inside, this columns will get its own grids with 12 columns inside, the difference is the width proportion between parents and childs.